# How to deploy a create-react-app using Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, create-react-app

I've spent the past 2 days trying to figure out how to deploy my web app using Azure DevOps but nothing shows up. I used FileZila to see if the files generated by the build is uploading and all the files are there under the `wwwroot` folder. I tried manually uploading the files using FileZilla too. At this point I'm getting really frustrated because I've tried everything I found online to deploy the app. DevOps works perfectly fine, the part that isn't working is my web app actually showing up when I go to the URL.

I followed all the tutorials I could find.

[image: This is what I see when I try to visit my site]

No idea why this is asking me to deploy my code when the code is clearly deployed :/

Comment: check whether the deployed files are available or not using Kudu Console.

Comment: @Sajeetharan when I go to the Kudu console and click on "Site wwwroot" all I see is a blank page. That doesn't make sense though, shouldn't the files show up there since I'm directly uploading them to the "wwwroot" folder?

Comment: are you trying to deploy to azure app service linux instance?

Answer (score 1):

Failed to reproduce your issue,you could follow my working steps as below:

1.Import repository,I used the git url from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript?view=azure-devops#package-web-apps):`https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/pipelines-javascript`

[image]

2.Create Build Pipeline.

[image]

3.Run the Build process.

[image]

4.Release the project and choose Nodejs Web APP.

[image]

5.Choosing the azure web app service in your subscription.

[image]

6.Navigate to your project url.

[image]

7.My files in the /wwwroot directory.

[image]

And `web.config` file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:

     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

      See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You could check any differences between your steps and mine.Any concern,please let me know.

Comment: Ahh I don't have a server file, I'm using `create-react-app`

Comment: @corasan So now,the issue is solved? Or do i need to do a test for you about create-react-app?

Comment: no, the issue isn't solved. This won't work because is not a node app, I'm uploading static build files to Azure App Service

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was having this issue was that I was trying to deploy to a Linux web app in Azure.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way around getting the deployment to Linux working, but as soon as I switched the app to windows based app service plan the app worked instantly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're deploying react app to azure app service linux instance via Azure devops, then be sure to add following 'Startup command' to the azure app service deployment task:

```
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa
```

> Azure App Service Linux uses Nginx for web server, and has pm2
> installed. Know more about pm2 here ->
> https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/
>
> To automatically redirect all queries to the index.html use the --spa
> option.

[image: Devops Azure App Service Deployment Task]

After devops run, your azure app service Configuration -> General Settings, will look like:

[image]